# OWIN self-host ASP.NET Web API does not receive cancellation token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

As the title says I tried sample from Microsoft site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api but I'm unable to get cancellation token to work with OWIN.

Modified the values controller `Get` to async method with logic to await on `Task.Delay`

```
await Task.Delay(5000, token) //where token is CancellationToken
```

Can someone help with what can be missing here or if there's an alternate way to cancel long running task while using OWIN self-hosted Web API.

I am using a console application built with .NET Framework 4.8 and verified cancel request using Postman. I also tried a sample ASP.NET Web API project with IIS Express and cancellation token works as expected